# SwiftUI DropDelegate, CONTINUATION MISUSE error in LoadObject

Tags: swiftui, async-await

I'm trying to write a function in DropDelegate that extracts a URL with async/await from a DropInfo using loadObject, and I'm getting the following error.

```
SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: extractURL(info:) leaked its continuation!
```

Here is the code:

```
func extractURL(info: DropInfo )async->URL?{
    return await withCheckedContinuation({ continuation in
        if let firstProvider = info.itemProviders( for: [.url]).first{
            let _ = firstProvider.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) { url, error in
                continuation.resume(returning: url)
            }
        }
        else{
            continuation.resume(returning: nil )
        }
    })
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: maybe a typo, you are missing a closing `}`

Comment: This error happens when you call the continuation more than once. loadObject is likely a dream

Comment: corrected the typo. thanks